# Rails 4 - removing array element from client and submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an array that I've made to have values added and removed on client side which then get persisted in the database when update action is triggered.

Adding/removing array values works excepts that with this approach, I cannot get rid of the last value of an array. Simply removing dom elements with Javascript and submitting this does nothing to the last value of an array.

I would like to be able to empty an array so with the page reload, blank field is presented for the first value entry.

**Removing array value**

```
$(document).on "click", ".delete_step", (event) ->
  cache = $(this).closest(".step_set")
  cache.fadeOut "fast", ->
    cache.remove()
    null
  event.preventDefault()
```

**Creating new field for new array value**

```
$(document).on "click", "#add_step", (event) ->
  html = "<div class='step_set'>" + "<input type='button' class='delete_step' value='Delete'>" + "<input type='text' name='recipe[steps][]'>" + "</div>"
  $( "#steps" ).append html
  event.preventDefault ()
```

**Controller**

```
def update
  if @recipe.update_attributes!(recipe_params)
    respond_with(@recipe)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :image, :serving, { steps: [] }, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
end
```

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for @recipe do |f| %>
  <button class="add" id="add_step">
    <span>+</span>Add Step
  </button>

  <fieldset id="steps"> 
    <% @recipe.steps.each_with_index do |individual_step, index| %>
      <div class="step_set" id="step_set<%= index %>">
        <a class="delete_step">Delete</a>
          <input type="text" value="<%= individual_step %>" name="recipe[steps][]">
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

After removing this element with delete and update

[image]

I still see this in the show page.

[image]

Comment: What is that "last value of array" ? How do you submit that ?

Comment: Try `parents('.step_set:first')` and could you give some example in jsfiddle?

Comment: I have no issue removing dom elements including the first one, the issue lies with submitting this form with no step elements present will still retain the first value of the array.

Comment: @alkuzad Hi, to be precise, it's the last value left in an array which I can't get rid of.

Comment: Please give me full example of this: `recipe_params[:recipe][:steps]`. steps are JSON/JSONB/HStore collection?

Comment: @Eraden Thanks for looking into this. I will share it later today when I have code handy. I'm using Postgresql array for steps which is supported in Rails 4. And, I believe it's JSON. Not sure about JSONB/HStore bit.

Comment: Hi @Eraden I've updated my question with the params definition. I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: @SeongLee I have a hunch that you're building your form using an object. Can you post your `views` please?

Comment: @Finks I've added view part in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that my hunch is correct. You're building your form with an object, `@recipe`. In your `update` action, `@recipe` still holds values and is carried over to your views.

How about trying to reinitialize `@recipe` in your `update` with `@recipe = @recipe.new` or something similar so that it's just an empty object of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your input, so you are saying reinitialise in the update action like `def update
@recipe = @recipe.new
  if @recipe.update_attributes!(recipe_params)
    respond_with(@recipe)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end`

Comment: Yes, something like that. Remember that when you build your form with an `object`, it retains the attributes when you render your view. Most of the time it's used to populate the fields when there's an error. But judging from your codes, you can use symbol in replace of your object -> `<%= simple_form_for :recipe %>`. Confirm this as I'm still vague on your code as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

1. As I understand, a `recipe` has many `steps`, right? So, `step` is a nested resource of `recipe`. You can check nested form tutorial here https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#specifying-a-target-for-nested-fields.
   It also supports add and remove link to remove a nested field.

Because inside the model, if I understand correctly (a recipe has many steps), so if we call `@recipe.steps`, you expect to return an array of steps, but actually, it's the result of a query

`SELECT * FROM steps WHERE recipe_id = #{id}`

So when you call `@recipe.update(st_here)`, it **do not** remove any `step`. That's why the step still appears in the next time you visit that recipe.

2. Did you use Turbolink? If yes, move the javascript inside this

   `ready = ->
     # YOUR CODE HERE
   $(document).ready(ready)`

And why not use `$(".delete_step").on("click", function() {})`, it's more readable and follow the convention.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Question on your point #1 - to return an array of steps rather than the result of a query, what do I need to do?

Comment: Oh, just simply convert it to array ``to_a``. Actually its behaviors is like an array (we can call ``@recipe.steps.each { # some cool thing }`` or ``first``, ``last``), and also is ActiveRecordRelation (ex: ``@recipe.steps.where(id: 4).order``). The problem I mentioned about ``steps`` isn't a real data of a recipe, it's a result of a query (``SELECT * FROM steps WHERE step.recipe_id = 1``)